# Is there a way to save a 3D plot in GNUplot as a 3D object?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I have a 3D plot that I made with the "splot" command. I found online that there is an open source file format ".STL" that allows you to save such 3D objects so that I can view them later, or share them with someone in all their 3D glory, instead of sharing "xy", "yz", and "zx" plane views individually.

Was wondering if that can be done from within GNUplot itself.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your data format? Please show some example data and your 3D plot. According to the manual there is no STL terminal. You need to write your own converter yourself. Depending on your exact data format, maybe there is a suitable converter out there.